primera columna vacía en treeview tkinter
llevo días haciendo una calculadora de matrices, ahora estoy en un problema y es que quiero que el resultado de una multiplicacion de matrices se muestre en una tabla de treeview pero por alguna razón los datos se insertan a partir de la columna 1 y la columna 0 queda vacía, he intentado de todo pero no logro hacer que los datos se agreguen desde la primera columna de la tabla, les agradezco si me pueden ayudar, o ilustrarme de como podría quedar el código para lograr hacerlo funcionar:
    def multiplicar_matrices():
        from main_structure import options_fm
        # Obtener los valores de las entradas
        matriz1 = []
    
        for i in range(p1_val):
            fila = []
            for j in range(p2_val):
                fila.append(float(matriz1_entries[i][j].get()))
            matriz1.append(fila)

        matriz2 = []
        
        for i in range(c1_val):
            fila = []
            for j in range(c2_val):
                fila.append(float(matriz2_entries[i][j].get()))
            matriz2.append(fila)
        
        # Multiplicar las matrices
        resultado = np.dot(matriz1, matriz2)

        # Crear una nueva ventana para mostrar el resultado
        for widget in raiz.winfo_children():
            if widget != options_fm:
                widget.destroy()

        frame_labelr=Frame(raiz)
        frame_labelr.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        ml_resultado = Label(frame_labelr, text="El resultado de la multiplicación es:", fg="#124559",
            font=("Poppins Medium", 18))
        ml_resultado.place(x=20, y=40)

        ml_resultado_m = Label(frame_labelr, text="M:", fg="#124559",
            font=("Poppins Medium", 15))
        ml_resultado_m.place(x=455, y=40)

        tree = ttk.Treeview(frame_labelr)
        tree.pack()

        scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(frame_labelr, orient="vertical", command=tree.yview)
        scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

        tree.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

        columns = ["Filas"]
        for i in range(len(resultado[0])):
            columns.append(f"Col {i + 1}")

        # Asignar las columnas al Treeview
        tree["columns"] = columns

        # Formatear columnas
        for i in range(len(resultado[0]) + 1):  # Aquí estaba el problema
            tree.column(i, anchor="center", width=40)
            if i == 0:
                tree.heading("#0", text="Filas")
            else:
                tree.heading(f"#{i}", text=f"Col {i}")

        # Insertar datos
        for i, (i, row) in enumerate(zip(range(len(resultado)), resultado)):
            tree.insert("", "end", values=[i] + list(row))


La primera columna es el identificador del item, debes asignarle el valor usando el argumento text, no a través de values:
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


resultado = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
])

root = tk.Tk()
frame_labelr = ttk.Frame(root)
frame_labelr.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

# ============================================================================== #

tree = ttk.Treeview(frame_labelr)
tree.pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(frame_labelr, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=tree.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

tree.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

n_filas, n_columnas = resultado.shape
columns = ["Filas"] + [f"Col {index}" for index in range(1, n_columnas + 1)]

# Asignar las columnas al Treeview
tree["columns"] = columns

# Formatear columnas
for index, column in enumerate(columns):
    tree.column(f"#{index}", anchor=tk.CENTER, width=40, stretch=tk.NO)
    tree.heading(f"#{index}", text=column)

# Insertar datos
for index, row in enumerate(resultado):
    tree.insert("", tk.END, text=index,  values=(*row,))

# ============================================================================== #

root.mainloop()


Nota: el código que te interesa es el encerrado entre las lineas
# ===...=== #, el resto es solo para hacer el ejemplo fácilmente reproducible.

También puedes ocultarla mediante el argumento/atributo show de TreeView y proceder como hacías antes:
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


resultado = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
])

root = tk.Tk()
frame_labelr = ttk.Frame(root)
frame_labelr.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

# ============================================================================== #

tree = ttk.Treeview(frame_labelr, show="headings")
tree.pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(frame_labelr, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=tree.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

tree.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

n_filas, n_columnas = resultado.shape
columns = ["Filas"] + [f"Col {index}" for index in range(1, n_columnas + 1)]

# Asignar las columnas al Treeview
tree["columns"] = columns

# Formatear columnas
for index, column in enumerate(columns):
    tree.column(f"#{index + 1}", anchor=tk.CENTER, width=40)
    tree.heading(f"#{index + 1}", text=column)

# Insertar datos
for index, row in enumerate(resultado):
    tree.insert("", tk.END, values=(index, *row))

# ============================================================================== #

root.mainloop()

En cualquier caso obtendrás algo como:


Amigo muchas gracias era justo lo que necesitaba!
